# Configure Tomcat with x509 certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ssl-certificate

I am trying to host my service with http and https. i have hosted in http and in https using keyStore generated using KeyStore tool.
Both of these worked.

Now i am trying to host x509 certificate and i am getting webpage is not available. i think issue is in configuring x509. let me know my mistake.

Working Setting, keystore

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="C:\apache server for hosting\keystore" 
           keystorePass="pass@word1" />
```

not working setting, x509 certificate

```
<Connector port="8444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"   
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"    
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEngine="on"          
    SSLCertificateFile="C:\apache server for hosting\JavaWebserviceCert.cer" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\apache server for hosting\JavaServicePrivateKey.pfx"  
    SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLVerifyDepth="10" />
```

Regards

Comment: What Tomcat version do you use? Is there any error message in log on startup?

Comment: apache-tomcat-7.0.50 , no error message logged in logs folder. when url is browsed for url which is protected by x509 i get "This webpage is not available".